# Build-time resource/layout selection in Eclipse for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

My company ships Android devices to control industrial equipment we make.   We only ship one specific device running Android 2.36 that we buy in quantity and load our own app on, so we don't have to worry about accommodating different layouts, resolutions, etc.

We have a customer in Israel who would like us to have the legends on our buttons in Hebrew.   Android 2.36 doesn't have good support for Hebrew (or RTL languages in general) so what we thought we would do is replace the text for these buttons with an image of the Hebrew text.

Since Hebrew is not a supported language on these devices I can't just put the whole device in Hebrew and have Android select the layout XML files with the images instead of text to use at runtime, so I think I might have to do it at build time, in other words have some kind of switch or setting that says use THESE layout resources instead of THOSE layout resources when building a Hebrew version of our product.

**My Question:** What's a good way to do that?  Is there a simple way to force it to use a particular set of layout XML files at build time or am I thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gradle for Android with Android Studio, this would be a fine place to use product flavors:

- Have the bulk of your code and resources be in the `main` sourceset as normal
- Define `standard` and `hebrew` product flavors in your `build.gradle` file
- Have the normal (non-Hebrew) resources be in a `standard` sourceset
- Have the Hebrew resources be in a `hebrew` sourceset

Then, a `hebrew` build will use the Hebrew layouts, while a `standard` build would use the normal layouts.

If Gradle for Android is not an option, since you control the hardware, you could drop some file in some special spot on the device, and check that when your process starts to determine if you should be in Hebrew-compatibility mode or not. This presumes that the users of the Android device do not have arbitrary access to it (so external storage would be safe) or that you inject the file into internal storage after installing your app (**`adb shell run-as`** should handle this, though I have only ever used it for read operations, not write operations).

Comment: Our current plan is to stick to Eclipse until Android Studio is a little less alpha or beta or whatever it is now . . . . . Dropping a file on the device and checking for it would be a runtime approach.   What would I do then?  Would I have to have a test in every activity where I do a _setContentView()_?   Are you saying there's no simple way at build-time to force it to build with one set of resource files versus another if I'm using Eclipse?

Comment: @user316117: "Would I have to have a test in every activity where I do a setContentView()?" -- no. Read in the file once and use it to populate a static data member that the rest of your code references. "Are you saying there's no simple way at build-time to force it to build with one set of resource files versus another if I'm using Eclipse?" -- you're welcome to move most of your code into an Android library project, then create two apps (one normal, one Hebrew) that reference the library. To me, that's more headache than this scenario is worth.

Comment: @CommonWare - "Read in the file once and use it to populate a static data member that the rest of your code references" ....  I get that part but I'm unclear on how that helps.  So I've got a static data member that says we're in Hebrew mode . . . How do I use that to force Android to use the Hebrew layout (XML) files instead of the default English ones?

Comment: @user316117: "How do I use that to force Android to use the Hebrew layout (XML) files instead of the default English ones?" -- `if` statements in your code, where you choose the resources to use (e.g., `R.layout.main` versus `R.layout.main_hebrew`).

Comment: ... that's what I was afraid of; that's why I was hoping for a build-time solution.   Oh well, thanks +1

Comment: @user316117: "that's why I was hoping for a build-time solution" -- which is Gradle for Android (see answer), or a library project and disparate apps (see first comment), or possibly *carefully* maintaining separate code branches in version control.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say you could use the layout-LANG to specify region based layouts, but I don't think you can do that if the language isn't supported there.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Does your app have a settings screen? You could simply have a setting to change all the layouts in run time.

Do you use Android Studio? Android studio allows different build profiles for debug, release, etc. You could set one up for Israel.

Comment: "Does your app have a settings screen? You could simply have a setting to change all the layouts in run time."   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   It does but then what do I do?   I don't want to clutter up my code with "if" statements all over the place that ask "am I in Hebrew or English?".   That could get really messy if we add other languages like Arabic, etc.  And even if I did how do I make it use the layout files with the picture buttons instead of the text buttons at runtime?

Comment: Create a Fragment/Activity that overides onCreate (Activity) or onCreateView(Fragment) and sets the different layout there. Then change your existing fragments/activies to extend those. Let me know if you don't understand what I'm saying, I'll type out code examples if you want.